# Can we use Spring WS for webservice of type RPC/ENCODED?

Tags: webservice-client

I have a WSDL of type RPC/Encoded and implementing Message Level Security (my XSD is complex type).

1. Can I use Spring WS for this type of Web Service?
2. is JAX-WS support this type of web service?

What is best way to implement this type of webservice? I need to implement the client.

Answer (score 1):

JAX-WS does not support RPC/Encoded type of web services. For this we can use Rampart and also for more reference we can also refer to WSO2